# Can't access my actual user account in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, openid

Following is my user account https://stackoverflow.com/users/262146/waheed

But I'm unable to access it, I believe I used `*****@yahoo.com` to register that account, but now when i try to recover it, i receive email in response saying that no account is being registered with this email.

If I used openID to login through yahoo, it asks me to create a new account, since there is no account present with this email.

Can anybody help me with recover it or has i lost it permanently?

Note: I registered the original account using Open ID from yahoo login.

Comment: Can you not login using the same openID? The email for you is not a `yahoo.com` address, but a `ymail.com` address. I will not disclose the actual address, as you should be able to access it (proving it does belong to you).

Comment: Also, if you can, follow [the merge guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I now know the account that i originally used and will try to login through it in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually login *with Yahoo*, as you used your Yahoo account to register. Click on the 'login' link at the top of the screen, click on the Yahoo icon, then authenticate at Yahoo. Once you have, you'll be redirected back to the site and logged in.

If you still can't manage to get into your account please [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and we'll get it sorted out.